Laravel Route Model Binding with custom key
I have a problem with route model binding in laravel 11. The response always stays empty, no matter what I try.
What do I have
I have a database table looking something like this:
* ------------------- *
|      favourites     |
* ------------------- *
|       user_id       |
|  favourite_user_id  |
* ------------------- *

I have no primary key, because it is only a relation between two different users, and the relation only needs to be queried by the user_id-column.
In my api.php file I defined the routes the following way:
Route::apiResource('favourites', FavouriteController::class)->only(['index', 'store', 'destroy']);

In my FavouritesController.php file I have the destroy-method defined as:
public function destroy(Request $request, Favourite $favourite)
{
    return [$favourite];
}

The output of php artisan route:list brings:
GET|HEAD        api/favourites
POST            api/favourites
DELETE          api/favourites/{favourite}

What do I need?
I want to use route model binding on the {favourite} variable from my api-endpoint. As the table has no id column, but a user_id instead, I tried various scenarios, but none worked. The $favourite variable from the destroy method is always empty.
What did I try?

Use getRouteKeyName() in the FavouriteController.php file

public function getRouteKeyName(): string
{
    return 'user_id';
}


Define the key name directly in the api.php file

Route::apiResource('favourites', FavouriteController::class)->only(['index', 'store', 'destroy'])->parameters(['favourite' => 'favourite:user_id']);


Split the routes in the api.php file

Route::apiResource('favourites', FavouriteController::class)->only(['index', 'store']);
Route::get('favourites/{favourites:user_id}', [FavouriteCountroller::class, 'destroy'])

But nothing seems to work. The return from Favourite in my controller is always empty.
Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks in advance
Edit
After hours of trying, I just skipped route model binding, imported the variable $favourite in my delete model as a string and did it the manual way (simplified):
public function destroy(Request $request, string $favouritePilot)
{
    Favourite::where('favourite_id', $favourite)->delete();

    return response()->noContent();
}


getRouteKeyName is a Model method, it is the Model telling what key it wants to be used

Laravel doesn't work well "out of the box" with Models which have a composite primary key. Although you say your table does not have a primary key, implicitly you have a composite key using both columns.
If you want to leverage route model binding, the simplest solution is to add an id auto increment primary key column to your favourites table and pass the id of the favourite relationship to the URL.
If you really don't want to add the id column the only other solution is to change the parameter from Favourite to User and then query the favourites table using the passed in user relation but that's not really helping much as you will still need to search the favourites table using the authenticated user's id and the passed in User.

thank you for the answer, the solution with querying by id works fine, but as every user_id can have many favourites, my goal was, to get all favourites by querying by the user_id column

Route binding gives you the Eloquent Model of an entity identified by the supplied primary key. It's not designed to return a collection of Models.

I know it would be really nice if you could have it work the way you describe, but I really recommend you add the primary key id column to favourites and let Laravel handle the rest. Save your energy for other problems you'll need to solve ;)

Thanks for the hint, I think I will do as you recommended
